# Permission set for Streaming API in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities, sfdc

Hello fellow developers,

I am currently working on implementing the Streaming API in Salesforce, and I'm wondering about the required permissions to ensure a smooth integration (which includes both channel creation and the channel subscription as well). I would appreciate any insights or guidance on the specific permissions required for using the Streaming API effectively.

After following couple of articles I found that **Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions** permission is a must for creating the channel but this is kind of an admin level privilege. So is there any workaround permission set which can be used here ?

I want to ensure that I have a comprehensive understanding of the permissions required to make the most of the Streaming API. Any information, tips, or best practices related to configuring permissions for the Streaming API would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!